# Buscar cierto código JavaScript en todo un proyecto desde Atom para su reemplazo

Tags: javascript, html5, atom-editor

Necesito buscar cierto código JavaScript que está incrustado dentro de muchas páginas .html dentro de mi proyecto desde mi editor de **Atom**, para luego reemplazarlo por otro código, también de JavaScript el cuál es una mejor versión.

El problema es que al hacer la búsqueda desde **Atom** no encuentra nada, cuando no debería ser así, ya que hay muchas páginas con el código a reemplazar. No estoy usando expresiones regulares ni nada de eso.
Yo necesito sólo cambiar esta parte:

```
if(month < 10){
        span.textContent = `${day}/0${month}/${year}`;
    }else{
        span.textContent = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    }
```

por esta otra:

```
if (month < 10 && day < 10) {
    span.textContent = `0${day}/0${month}/${year}`;
  } else if (month < 10) {
    span.textContent = `${day}/0${month}/${year}`;
  } else if (day < 10) {
    span.textContent = `0${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  } else {
    span.textContent = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  }
```

Quizás al ser un código lo que se busca, **Atom** lo interpreta de otra forma, porque yo he probado con otras cosas a buscar (sólo texto, tags, etc.) y si lo encuentra.

Comment: Aparte del problema de búsqueda, tienes otro muy importante: Repetir código; revisa la sección **DRY** de [este artículo](https://tantacom.com/principios-diseno-software-kiss-dry-solid/). Deberías crear una función que puedas llamar cada que la necesites en lugar de volver a colocar todas las condiciones.

Comment: En _ATOM_ hay un [ticket abierto](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/218) para reportar que la búsqueda (y remplazo) multilínea en todo el proyecto no funciona. Seguramente tendrás que buscar solo `if(month < 10)` o alguna otra cadena específica del bloque y remplazar manualmente.

Comment: También puedes reducir el código evitando las comparaciones con [str.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart), convirtiendo primero a cadena: `span.textContent = \`${day.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${month.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${year}\`;`

Comment: @Triby Entiendo lo de crear una función, pero ya estaba realizado así. De todas formas tengo que hacer el reemplazo si hago dicha función. Ahora pregunto, ¿debo crear un nuevo archivo javascript para crear esa función en dicho archivo nuevo? ¿y después llamar a ese archivo desde todas las páginas .html?

Comment: ¿No tienes un archivo `.js` con funciones comunes que uses en todo el proyecto? Ahí es donde deberías colocar la función.

Comment: Bueno, al final lo solucioné con otro editor (Notepad++). Ademas de mejorar el código y hacerlo todo en un archivo con una función, pude reemplazar todo ese código por la función con el Notepad++ que si permite buscar multilíneas, me salvo porque eran más de 400 archivos a actualizar.